# Unix - Systemd: basic.target

Tags: unix, raspberry-pi3, embedded-linux, systemd, systemctl

I accidentally set the default systemctl target to basic target while trying to switch from multi-user to graphical target on my raspberry Pi 3B which runs the Raspbian OS. Since then when I boot my RPi it does not start and only displays a welcoming screen. I tried to edit the config and cmdline files while in recovery mode to try to access the command line but I could not. Can someone explain to me what the basic target even is because I have been searching online for hours and cannot find a proper explanation? Do I need to format my RPi now or can I access my command line by some way to switch to multi-user target?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for all systemd so-called *special* units is available under `systemd.special(7)` man page (or in the respective [online version](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html)).

`basic.target` is an early-boot synchronization point, ordered even before initrd, so the service for login prompts is simply not started, thus there's no command line to work with. This is nicely described and visualized in the [bootup(7)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/bootup.html) man page.

You can temporarily override the default target from the kernel command line using the `systemd.unit=` argument ([systemd(1)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.html), section *Kernel Command Line*).

In your case, adding `systemd.unit=multi-user.target` to your kernel command line should be enough to allow you to boot back into your rPi and then make the target change permanent by calling `systemctl set-default multi-user.target` (or `graphical.target`, as that seems to be the original way you were trying to follow).